# Session time out set by Curator Framework

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have just started using curator framework and found something that was very interesting and wanted to check if I my assumption is correct. Session time out in Zookeeper is twice the tikr time. So in my local zookeeper config file my tikr time is 8 seconds so the session time out becomes 16 seconds. Now when I create curator framework and set session time out to a value less than 16 seconds the negotiated session time out is set to 16 seconds but if I set the session timeout in the curator framework to say 25 seconds then the negotiated session time out is 25 seconds. Is it right to assume that the greater of the 2 values is set as session time out value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client sends a requested timeout, the ZK server responds with the timeout that it can give the client.

> The current implementation requires that the timeout be a minimum of **2** times the tickTime (as set in the server configuration) and a maximum of **20** times the tickTime.

So a value less than 16 (8 * 2) will be increased to 16, and 25 is okay.

See https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkSessions for more details